# Angular-cli, PrimeNG and angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Could someone Help:  I am trying to get PrimeNG working with an Angular application created with angular-cli.  I installed PrimeNG in my new application (created with CLI) but I can't get the styling to work.  The PrimeNG website states that I need to add the following to my Index.html

```
href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"
href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
href="./assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
```

Note I have tried that and I tried adding these to the angular-cli.json files styles array and still now luck.

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "./assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      ]
```

Could someone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone has this issue, here are the steps that I finally used to get this working.   First.  Create a fresh project with the 'angular-cli'.  Second:  cd to the root of your new application and install PrimeNG and run $npm install primeng --save.  Third:  Add the style paths to the styles: [ ] array in your projects 'angular-cli.json' file.  Fith: install font-awesome in your project (this is required) $npm install font-awesome --save.  That worked for me.!

Answer (score 1):

In your project folder there is a folder called styles.css go into that and try this.

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import url('../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css');
@import url('../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css');
@import url('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
@import url('../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your path and files, these settings might be outdated.
For example, [primeNG is delivered](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/master/resources/themes/omega) with `omega/theme.scss` and not css. This file might not be exist in your `node_modules` directory.

I've used the following settings in my angular-cli and it seems to work just fine:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css"
  ]
```

Note that angular-cli (beta-30) will attach these files content as `<style>` tags.

Also, I've did something similar in the last few days (angular-cli project with primeNG components) - Try out my (still under construction) [demo repository](https://github.com/yuvalbl/ng2-grids-demo), it uses primeUI for styles, but it might help. You might want to take a look at the angular-cli.json in this project.